# Is it OK to have multiple assertions in a unit test when testing complex behavior?

Tags: actionscript-3, unit-testing, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexunit4

Here is my specific scenario.

I have a class `QueryQueue` that wraps the `QueryTask` class within the ArcGIS API for Flex. This enables me to easily queue up multiple query tasks for execution. Calling `QueryQueue.execute()` iterate through all the tasks in my queue and call their execute method.

When all the results have been received and processed `QueryQueue` will dispatch the completed event. The interface to my class is very simple.

```
public interface IQueryQueue
{
    function get inProgress():Boolean;
    function get count():int;

    function get completed():ISignal;
    function get canceled():ISignal;

    function add(query:Query, url:String, token:Object = null):void; 
    function cancel():void;
    function execute():void;
}
```

For the `QueryQueue.execute` method to be considered successful several things must occur.

1. `task.execute` must be called on each query task once and only once
2. `inProgress = true` while the results are pending
3. `inProgress = false` when the results have been processed
4. `completed` is dispatched when the results have been processed
5. `canceled` is never called
6. The processing done within the queue correctly processes and packages the query results

What I am struggling with is breaking these tests into readable, logical, and maintainable tests.

Logically I am testing one *state*, that is the successful execution state. This would suggest one unit test that would assert #1 through #6 above are true.

```
[Test] public mustReturnQueryQueueEventArgsWithResultsAndNoErrorsWhenAllQueriesAreSuccessful:void
```

However, the name of the test is not informative as it does not describe all the things that must be true in order to be considered a passing test.

Reading up online (including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735737/multiple-assertions-when-unit-testing-constructor) and at [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/is-it-ok-to-have-multiple-asserts-in-a-single-unit-test)) there is a sizable camp that asserts that unit tests should only have one assertion (as a guideline). As a result when a test fails you know exactly what failed (i.e. inProgress not set to true, completed displayed multiple times, etc.) You wind up with potentially a lot more (but in theory simpler and clearer) tests like so:

```
[Test] public mustInvokeExecuteForEachQueryTaskWhenQueueIsNotEmpty():void
[Test] public mustBeInProgressWhenResultsArePending():void
[Test] public mustNotInProgressWhenResultsAreProcessedAndSent:void
[Test] public mustDispatchTheCompletedEventWhenAllResultsProcessed():void
[Test] public mustNeverDispatchTheCanceledEventWhenNotCanceled():void
[Test] public mustReturnQueryQueueEventArgsWithResultsAndNoErrorsWhenAllQueriesAreSuccessful:void
// ... and so on
```

This could wind up with a lot of repeated code in the tests, but that could be minimized with appropriate `setup` and `teardown` methods.

While this question is similar to other questions I am looking for an answer for this specific scenario as I think it is a good representation of a complex unit testing scenario exhibiting multiple states and behaviors that need to be verified. Many of the other questions have, unfortunately, no examples or the examples do not demonstrate complex state and behavior.

Comment: The idea that each unit test should have only one assert is [impractical and short sighted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20300843/545127).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on the tests you have identified first. All except the last one (`mustReturnQueryQueueEventArgs...`) are good ones and I could immediatelly tell what's being tested there (and that's very good sign, indicating they're descriptive and most likely simple).

The only problem is your last test. Note that extensive use of words *"and"*, *"with"*, *"or"* in test name usually rings problems bell. It's not very clear what it's supposed to do. Return correct results comes to mind first, but one might argue it's vague term? This holds true, it is vague. However you'll often find out that this is indeed pretty common requirement, described in details by method/operation contract.

In your particular case, I'd simplify last test to verify whether correct results are returned and that would be all. You tested states, events and stuff that lead to results building already, so there is no need to that again.

Now, advices in links you provided are quite good ones actually, and *generally*, I suggest sticking to them (single assertion for one test). The question is, what *single assertion* really stands for? 1 line of code at the end of test? Let's consider this simple example then:

```
// a method which updates two fields of our custom entity, MyEntity
public void Update(MyEntity entity)
{
    entity.Name = "some name";
    entity.Value = "some value";
}
```

This method contract is to perform those 2 operations. By success, we understand entity to be correctly updated. If one of them for some reasons fails, method as a unit is considered to fail. You can see where this is going; you'll either have two assertions or write custom comparer purely for testing purposes.

Don't be tricked by *single assertion*; it's not about lines of code or number of asserts (however, in **majority** of tests you'll write this will indeed map 1:1), but about asserting *single unit* (in the example above, *update* is considered to be an unit). And unit might be in reality multiple things that don't make any sense at all without eachother.

And this is exactly what one of questions you linked quotes (by Roy Osherove):

> My guideline is usually that you test one logical CONCEPT per test. you can have multiple asserts on the same object. they will usually be the same concept being tested.

It's all about concept/responsibility; not the number of asserts.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, and there will probably be many, there are a couple of things here:

1. If you must test so many things for one method, then it could mean your code might be doing too much in one single method ([Single Responsibility Principle)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
2. If you disagree with the above, then the next thing I would say is that what you are describing is more of an integration/acceptance test. Which allows for multiple asserts, and you have no problems there. But, keep in mind that this might need to be relegated to a separate section of tests if you are doing automated tests (safe versus unsafe tests)
3. And/Or, yes, the preferred method is to test each piece separately as that is what a **unit** test is. The closest thing I can suggest, and this is about your tolerance for writing code just to have perfect tests...Is to check an object against an object (so you would do one assert that essentially tests this all in one). However, the argument against this is that, yes it passes the one assert per test test, but you still lose expressiveness.

Ultimately, your goal should be to strive towards the ideal (one assert per **unit** test) by focusing on the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29), but ultimately you do need to get things done or else there is no real point in writing software (my opinion at least :)).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with flex, but I think I have good experience in unit testing, so you have to know that unit test is a philosophy, so for the first answer, yes you can make a multiple assert but if you test the same behavior, the main point always in unit testing is to be very maintainable and simple code, otherwise the unit test will need unit test to test it! So my advice to you is, if you are new in unit testing, don't use multiple assert, but if you have good experience with unit testing, you will know when you will need to use them