# RSpec: how to test Rails logger message expectations?

Tags: logging, rspec, mocking, stubbing

I am trying to test that the Rails logger receives messages in some of my specs.  I am using the [Logging gem](https://github.com/TwP/logging).

Let's say that I have a class like this:

```
class BaseWorker

  def execute
    logger.info 'Starting the worker...'
  end

end
```

And a spec like:

```
describe BaseWorker do

  it 'should log an info message' do
    base_worker = BaseWorker.new
    logger_mock = double('Logging::Rails').as_null_object
    Logging::Rails.stub_chain(:logger, :info).and_return(logger_mock)

    logger_mock.should_receive(:info).with('Starting the worker...')
    base_worker.execute
    Logging::Rails.unstub(:logger)
  end

end
```

I get the following failure message:

```
 Failure/Error: logger_mock.should_receive(:info).with('Starting worker...')
   (Double "Logging::Rails").info("Starting worker...")
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
```

I've tried out several different approaches to get the spec to pass.  This works for example:

```
class BaseWorker

  attr_accessor :log

  def initialize
    @log = logger
  end

  def execute
    @log.info 'Starting the worker...'
  end

end

describe BaseWorker do
  it 'should log an info message' do
    base_worker = BaseWorker.new
    logger_mock = double('logger')
    base_worker.log = logger_mock

    logger_mock.should_receive(:info).with('Starting the worker...')
    base_worker.execute
  end
end
```

But having to setup an accessible instance variable like that seems like the tail is wagging the dog here. (Actually, I'm not even sure why copying logger to @log would make it pass.)

What's a good solution for testing the logging?

Comment: That question did arise several times on SO, see for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153234/how-deep-are-your-unit-tests) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168151/unit-testing-logging-and-dependency-injection) and the general consensus was that you don't test logging unless it's a project requirement.

Comment: Art, thanks for the comment.  I did read those ones.  That may be the ultimate answer.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

While I agree you generally don't want to test loggers, there are times it may be useful.

I have had success with expectations on `Rails.logger`.

Using RSpec's deprecated `should` syntax:

```
Rails.logger.should_receive(:info).with("some message")
```

Using RSpec's newer `expect` syntax:

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with("some message")
```

**Note:** In controller and model specs, you have to put this line *before* the message is logged. If you put it after, you'll get an error message like this:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with("some message")
       (#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x007f27f72136c8>).info("some message")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("some message")
           received: 0 times
```

Comment: I have the similar case expect my expected string is a partial string, I could not figure out so far, how to deal with it, any help?

Comment: @AmolPujari 

    `expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with(/partial_string/)`

where "partial_string" is the string you're looking for. Simple Regex compare

Comment: This is great, I'm checking I don't get *anything at all* logged to error and checking against Rspec's anything matcher does this nicely:

`expect(Rails.logger).to_not receive(:error).with(anything)`

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "you have to put this line before the message is logged"? The expectation appears in the code before the code that generates the log? I'm doing that and getting an error because the logger is getting the message that is logged from stuff being done in my `let` expressions before the `it` block even runs

Comment: @sixty4bit it means, that expext.. receive works as an event listener - you have to set it up first and then launch the code that will log the message you want to catch

Comment: Does this not work in feature specs (as opposed to controller specs)? I'm using the code above: `expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with(/foobar/)`, placed before the spec code that will generate logging. I can plainly see the `foobar` statement in `test.log` after the spec runs, but the spec fails with the error above.

Answer (score 26):

With RSpec 3+ version

**Actual code containing single invocation of `Rails.logger.error`**:

```
Rails.logger.error "Some useful error message"
```

Spec code:

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).with(/error message/)
```

If you want the error message to be actually logged while the spec runs then use following code:

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).with(/error message/).and_call_original
```

**Actual code containing multiple invocations of `Rails.logger.error`**:

```
Rails.logger.error "Technical Error Message"
Rails.logger.error "User-friendly Error Message"
```

Spec code:

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).ordered
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).with(/User-friendly Error /).ordered.and_call_original
```

***Also if you care about just matching the first message and not any subsequent messages then you can use following***

```
  expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:debug).with("Technical Error Message").ordered.and_call_original
  expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:debug).at_least(:once).with(instance_of(String)).ordered
```

*Note in above variation setting `.ordered` is important else expectations set start failing.*

References:

http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/setting-constraints/message-order

Answer (score 23):

Instead of using this line *before* the message is logged:

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with("some message")
something that triggers the logger...
```

You could set the Rails logger as a spy and use `have_received` instead:

```
allow(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).at_least(:once)

something that triggers the logger...

expect(Rails.logger).to have_received(:info).with("some message").once
```

Comment: I used the first approach but why this `expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with("A Report processing is already scheduled for: #{report.inspect}")` was giving this error: `expected: ("A Report processing is already scheduled for: #<Report id: 2677, org_id: 6649, user_id: ...tion: nil, life_state: \"ideation\", chat_link: nil, discarded_at: nil, registrants_count: 2>") ---> got: ("A Report processing is already scheduled for: [#<Report id: 2677, org_id: 6649, user_id:...ion: nil, life_state: \"ideation\", chat_link: nil, discarded_at: nil, registrants_count: 2>]") (1 time)`

Answer (score 12):

If your goal is to test logging functionality you may also consider verifying the output to standard streams.

This will spare you the mocking process and test whether messages will actually end up where they supposed to (STDOUT/STDERR).

With RSpec's [output matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher) (introduced in 3.0) you can do the following:

```
expect { my_method }.to output("my message").to_stdout
expect { my_method }.to output("my error").to_stderr
```

In case of libraries such as `Logger` or `Logging` you may have to use `output.to_<>_from_any_process`.

Comment: The `_from_any_process` was what I was missing! Took way too long to find this. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to keep consistency in your tests, but setting the expectations at last you need to add in your setup:

```
setup do
 allow(Rails.logger).to receive(:info)
end
...

it 'should log an info message' do
 {code}

  expect(Rails.logger).to have_received(:info).with('Starting the worker...')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are already many answers for asserting the Rails.logger.info message using RSpec.

I am going to explain: How to assert the `Rails.logger.info` message in a unit test without using RSpec in the Ruby on Rails application.

```
require "stringio"
class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_log_output
    output = StringIO.new
    Rails.logger = Logger.new(output)
    
    # Make the API call or method that generates the log message
    some_method_that_logs()
    
    # Assert the log message
    assert_match("Expected log message", output.string)
  end
end
```

1. You can capture the output from `Rails.logger` by creating a `StringIO` object and setting it as the logger's output.
2. This will redirect all log messages to the `StringIO` object, allowing you to inspect the log messages later in the test.

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Even I had very similar error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with("some message")
       (#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x007f27f72136c8>).info("some message")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("some message")
           received: 0 times
```

The below worked for me,

```
expect { my_method }.
            to output(/error messsage/).to_stdout_from_any_process
```

Reference: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher