# How to test log content with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, testing, rspec

For example, it generated a log(my_work.log) content as:

```
I, [2015-05-14T00:00:00.000000 #5590]  INFO -- : Work started.
```

I want to test if my_work.log has content `Work started.`, how to do?

I don't want to match all line include datetime, because that contains `#5590`, I can't stub it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass in an instance of StringIO when initializing Logger to capture the output and then match on the expected content:

```
require 'logger'

describe "log" do
  let(:log) { StringIO.new }
  let(:logger) { Logger.new(log) }
  let(:expected) { "Work started" }

  it "should add the expected content to the log" do
    logger.info(expected)
    log.rewind
    expect(log.read).to match(/.+#{expected}$/)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

`Rails.logger` uses some methods to log things, for example:

- debug
- info
- fatal
- warn

So in your case you use `info`, to log something, instead loking for a match, you can detect if method `info` was called:

```
it 'logs exception' do
  # some code
  expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info)
  # execute the line that logs something
end
```

Even you can add parameters to `receive` method with reserved word `with`:

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with('Work started.')
```

This cause you need to specify something

Check [rspec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages) and [rails logger](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels)

Also check [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998160/rspec-how-to-test-rails-logger-message-expectations)

Answer (score 3):

With RSpec's [output matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher) (introduced in 3.0) you can do the following:

```
expect { my_method }.to output("my message").to_stdout
expect { my_method }.to output("my error").to_stderr
```

In case of libraries such as `Logger` or `Logging` you may have to use `output.to_<stdout/stderr>_from_any_process`.

It's simple, clean and will test whether your messages actually reach the output.