# How do I test Rails logging from an Rspec feature spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, rspec

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998160/rspec-how-to-test-rails-logger-message-expectations) tells me how to test logger statements from RSpec model and controller specs. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work from a feature spec. With this code:

```
# controller.rb
def action
  logger.info 'foobar'
end

# spec.rb
scenario 'logging should work' do
  expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:info).with('foobar')
  visit action_path
end
```

I get the error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit action_path
   #<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x007ff45b6e5ad0> received :info with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("foobar")
          got: (no args)
```

The `test.log` file does not contain `foobar`, so it seems the test is failing immediately, before the controller action has a chance to complete.

Is there some way to use this `expect(Rails.logger)` syntax in a feature spec?

Comment: Any answers here?

Comment: This answer may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770552/how-to-get-rails-logger-printing-to-the-console-stdout-when-running-rspec/32628272#32628272

Answer (score 2):

The [Rails.logger.info method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-info) can take a string or a block. If you're invoking the block form then it will give this "got: (no args)" output.

For example

```
logger.info 'foobar'
```

...all on one line will call .info with a string, but if you do

```
logger.info
  "foobar foobar longer message so I'll put it on its own line"
```

split across two lines without brackets, then you're actually passing a block. Add some brackets...

```
logger.info(
  "foobar foobar longer message so I'll put it on its own line"
)
```

...and you're back to a string.

*He says knowingly after bashing his head on this problem for a few hours :-)*

Before realising that, I started figuring out how to mock the Rails.logger class. That might be a useful approach for you or others. Maybe you're calling with a block for some other reason (something to do with feature vs controller specs?), or maybe you can't change the calling code, in which case... something like this might be a useful starting point:

```
class LoggerMock < Object
  def initialize; end

  def info(progname = nil, &block)
    mock_info(block.call)
  end
end
```

and

```
logger_mock = LoggerMock.new
allow(Rails).to receive(:logger).and_return(logger_mock)
expect(logger_mock).to receive(:mock_info).with('foobar')
```