# How do you unit test code that relies on randomly generated numbers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, random, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

What is the best way to unit test code that relies on you randomly generating data? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288096/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-functions-that-rely-on-dynamic-data) question on stack overflow but it is a little different. I know that you can use fixtures to mock out something like a database but I think that what I'm trying to do is a little different.

I'm trying to write an [adaline neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADALINE). This requires me to randomly generate weights and then the values for the weights are adjusted as more data is presented to the network. How do I unit test something like this? I've started writing tests for the parts that don't rely on random inputs, but I don't know how to handle this part.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: make a moku-up for the component that generates number so it becomes predictable

Comment: Can you unit test with a fixed seed?

Comment: @Phylogenesis I'm using the random method in Java's Math class similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/363732/667440). I'm not providing a seed for random number generation.

Comment: About ten years ago when I was taking software engineering courses towards an MSCS, I asked that very same question.  I was told it would make an excellent master's thesis project.  So at the time, it was not an easy question to answer.

Comment: @Novak I'm in graduate school also...but I want to do my thesis project on something else.

Comment: @j.jerod.taylor I said that, too!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `new Random(seed)` to get deterministic random number all the time. [Why non-deterministic tests are a problem? Click here to see why](http://martinfowler.com/articles/nonDeterminism.html)