# Testing ViewModels in MVVMCorss

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have just started working with MVVMCross for a cross platform app and I am having a hard time figuring out how to test my ViewModels. I tried following the testing done in TwitterSearch and ran into problems. Specifically in the MockSetup.cs I found that in the latest version of MvvmCross there no longer seems to be a `IMvxViewDispatcherProvider` but that is ok because I *think* its functionality has been rolled up into the `IMvxViewDispatcher`. However, when actually setting up the dipatcher for my test cases there is no `RequestNavigate` method for the dispatcher anymore and I can not find an implementation of `MvxShowViewModelRequest`. So I can not actually get any tests for my ViewModels to work.

I also tried to follow the testing here http://slodge.blogspot.com/2012/10/testing-viewmodels-in-mvvmcross.html but again ran into issues with missing `MvxOpenNetCfServiceProviderSetup`.

So in summary, my issue has been getting a MockSetup working so that I can test my ViewModels. If I could just be pointed in the right direction on the dispatcher, I think that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to test an mvvmcross v3 application using mvvmcross vnext objects.

The updated twitter search test for v3 is at https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.Test

This test uses a single special mock object: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.Test/Mocks/MockMvxViewDispatcher.cs

The role of this mock is just currently:

- to provide a very simple main thread (it uses the current thread)
- to provide simple storage for any navigation requests.

You can see it used in:

- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch/TwitterSearch.Test/HomeViewModelTest.cs