# Spring Junit test case for controller rest service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test

I have a controller which responds to REST calls, I have various test cases for my other public methods.

I do not know how to write one for my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/frames", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Frame> getFrames(
  @RequestParam(value="frameLength", required=true) Double frameLength,
  @RequestParam(value="frameBreadth", required=true) Double frameBreadth,
  @RequestParam(value="mountThickness", required=true) Double mountThickness,
  @RequestParam(value="frameThickness", required=true) Double frameThickness){
    List<Frame> tempFrames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<FrameVariant> frameVariants = frameVariantService.getFrames(
      frameLength, frameBreadth, mountThickness, frameThickness);
    for (FrameVariant frameVariant : frameVariants) {
      tempFrames.add(new Frame(frameVariant));
    }
    return tempFrames;
  }
```

I have no clue how to write a test case for this controller method.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think unit testing *this* method is of much worth. The only thing you can really check is that it correctly forwards the parameters to `getFrames` function and then converts each `FrameVariant` to a `Frame`. Both that function and the conversion constructor should unit tested any way. This functionality should be tested as end to end testing, ie deploy this service (and a 'test data set') and make an actual HTTP requests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-server). It's part of Spring Test module.

[These tutorials](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-rest-api/) are pretty descriptive and going into details so you should get idea straight away how to test Spring MVC controllers.

Comment: @luboskmac, is it alright to use mock mvc for testing rest?

Comment: Do you have some objections why it wouldn't? From my point of view, team has to decide what is most effective testing for them. http://stackoverflow.com/a/153565/1919879